# Toggle keys in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

My goal is mapping WASD to the 4 arrow buttons on the keyboard and make 1 'Suspend' the script while z exits it. That was easy enough. Now I'd like `a` and `d` only apply conditionally. I look at the docs and I have no idea what's wrong here. I think I'm either using the if statement wrong or Left/Right doesn't work in if statements in which case I have no idea what to do.

```
#SingleInstance
a::if(UseAD) Left
d::if(UseAD) Right
1::Suspend
2::UseAD:=!UseAD
w::Up
s::Down
z::ExitApp
```

Comment: you can make `2::` call the `Hotkey` command. It was made for this very problem and can alter the `a` / `d` behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#SingleInstance
$a::Send % UseAD ? "{Left}" : "a" 
$d::Send % UseAD ? "{Right}" : "d" 
1::Suspend
2::UseAD:=!UseAD
w::Up
s::Down
z::ExitApp
```

Okay now a break down.

Your [If](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfEqual.htm) statement wasn't being evaluated correctly. The following line of code after the condition is met is what is run. Like so:

```
If (true)
    do this
```

Your [Hotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) is also wrong for a Multi lined statement. Essentially a single lined Hotkey is a basically a Send command for whatever key or keys specified on that line (unless you specify an assignment/function/command etc...) it will act as a Send Command does. To have an If evaluation requires multiple lines. When you specify a hotkey and you want an evaluation that will require multiple lines you, and must return from a Multi-Lined Hotkey same a Sub Routine:

```
a::
   Code goes here
   more code
   etc..
Return 

b::AnotherHotkey 

etc..
```

Okay so lets plug this Logic in with your code:

```
#SingleInstance
a::
    if(UseAD) 
       Left
return

d::
   if(UseAD) 
       Right
return

1::Suspend
2::UseAD:=!UseAD
w::Up
s::Down
z::ExitApp
```

If you run this you'll get an Error about the Text Left... that is because instead of our Hotkey acting as Send command it's acting as a Sub Routine so we have to specify Send command with Left:

```
a::
    if(UseAD) 
        Send, Left
return
```

But this isn't correct either, now it's sending the word Left instead of the [Key](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) left.. so again we have add Brackets around our named key like so:

```
a::
    if(UseAD) 
        Send, {Left}
return
```

Okay, now <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> are not being sent when UseAD is False, so we must [Send](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) them by specifying with [Else](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Else.htm) like so:

```
a::
    if(UseAD) 
        Send, {Left}
    else
        Send, a
return
```

Now we run this code and press <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>b</kbd> get an Max Hotkeys reached message because our code is triggering the Hotkey in an Infinate loop. We need to specify our code in such a way that it will not trigger itself, like so:

```
$a::
    if(UseAD) 
        Send, {Left}
    else
        Send, a
return
```

If you notice we have added a $ symbol in front of our hotkey, this adds a keyboard Hook to that Hotkey and will prevent the the script from triggering that hotkey itself. This is now a complete working script but looks entirely different from the first code I posted. That is because I like typing less lines, if I can.

In the first code sample I'm using a Forced Expression % on the Send command and Ternary ? : to evaluate UseAD and if true send Left key if false send the letter, exactly the same as above code, just more concise.